# Get list of running processes on Android 5.0

Tags: android, process

I'm new to Android. I've read various tutorials to get the list of running processes, and I've tried the following:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

However `RunningAppProcessInfo` contains only one app, the one I'm developing.

Also I've tried adding the permission `android.permission.GET_TASKS` in the manifest but it is deprecated. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: After few more research. So what I see is expected on Lollipop (security reason). Now I'm wondering: how to develop a "task manager app" on 5.0 ?